Python post request with json body to Spring Boot server gets redirected to login page
I am using a Python client to submit a post request to a Spring Boot application server. Instead of executing the controller method that has been mapped to the url, the server appears to redirect the request (status 302) to the login page. Web security on the server is configured to allow access to this url without requiring a login. What might be the cause? Really appreciate any help.
My client code is as follows.
import requests
import logging
import http.client as http_client

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

data = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 'value3',
    'key4': 'value4',
    'key5': 'value5',
    'key6': 'value6'
}

print("Sending headers and body =============\n")
print(f"Data: {data}")
print(f"Headers: {headers}")
print("end headers and body =============\n\n\n\n")
        
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

response = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/myApp/v1/type/service", data=data,  
       headers=headers)
print("Request processed =============\n\n\n\n")

print("Start response fields =============\n")
print(f"Request URL: {response.request.url}")
print(f"Request Headers: {response.request.headers}")
print(f"Request Body: {response.request.body}")
        
print(f"Response Status Code: {response.status_code}")
print(f"Response Body: {response.text}")
print("End response fields =============\n\n\n\n")

The security config is as follows.
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new LoginCredentialsDetailsJpaManager();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
        
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .requestMatchers("/myApp/v1/accounts/login", 
                    "/myApp/v1/type/service").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .formLogin((form) -> form
            .loginPage("/myApp/v1/accounts/login")
            .permitAll()
        )
        .logout((logout) ->
            logout.deleteCookies("remove")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.done")
                .permitAll()
        );
        
        return http.build();
    }
}

The controller method is defined as follows.
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping"/myApp/v1/type/service")
    public String populateObjects(@ModelAttribute TestObj testObj) {
        // Populate objects
        return "homePage";
    }

}

TestObj is defined as follows:
public class TestObj {
    
    private String key1;
    private String key2;
    private String key3;
    private String key4;
    private String key5;
    private String key6;

        // Getters and setters...

}

Executing the test client should have resulted in the controller method invocation, which returns the home page (placeholder for now). Instead we get the following output.
Sending headers and body =============
Data: {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4', 'key5': 'value5', 'key6': 'value6'}
Headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
end headers and body =============


DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:8080
send: b'POST /myApp/v1/type/service HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:8080\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.32.3\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 71\r\n\r\n'
send: b'key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3&key4=value4&key5=value5&key6=value6'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 \r\n'
header: Vary: Origin
header: Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
header: Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
header: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=8C43E31342E7B70CF2621763CD763004; Path=/; HttpOnly
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: X-XSS-Protection: 0
header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: Expires: 0
header: X-Frame-Options: DENY
header: Location: http://localhost:8080/myApp/v1/accounts/login;jsessionid=8C43E31342E7B70CF2621763CD763004
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2024 16:48:27 GMT
header: Keep-Alive: timeout=60
header: Connection: keep-alive
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:8080 "POST /myApp/v1/type/service HTTP/11" 302 0
send: b'GET /myApp/v1/accounts/login;jsessionid=8C43E31342E7B70CF2621763CD763004 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:8080\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.32.3\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nCookie: JSESSIONID=8C43E31342E7B70CF2621763CD763004\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 \r\n'
header: Location: http://localhost:8080/myApp/v1/accounts/login
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2024 16:48:27 GMT
header: Keep-Alive: timeout=60
header: Connection: keep-alive
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:8080 "GET /myApp/v1/accounts/login;jsessionid=8C43E31342E7B70CF2621763CD763004 HTTP/11" 302 0
send: b'GET /myApp/v1/accounts/login HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:8080\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.32.3\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nCookie: JSESSIONID=8C43E31342E7B70CF2621763CD763004\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 \r\n'
header: Vary: Origin
header: Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
header: Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: X-XSS-Protection: 0
header: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: Expires: 0
header: X-Frame-Options: DENY
header: Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
header: Content-Language: en-US
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Date: Tue, 17 Sep 2024 16:48:27 GMT
header: Keep-Alive: timeout=60
header: Connection: keep-alive
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:8080 "GET /myApp/v1/accounts/login HTTP/11" 200 None
Request processed =============

Start response fields =============

Request URL: http://localhost:8080/myApp/v1/accounts/login
Request Headers: {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.32.3', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=8C43E31342E7B70CF2621763CD763004'}
Request Body: None
Response Status Code: 200
Response Body: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>MyLogin</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>MyLogin</h1>
    
    <form action="/myApp/v1/accounts/login" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="rnuIrk2xyQYa1D8k2p7roGTJeM9b_QigtTibmpXsp9kB4FYClku_mX6B-DA3sQpF77PfllKsVa46xD2Ng1n5oqONk79n2GY0"/>
        <p>Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" /></p>
        <p>Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Sign In" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
        
    </form>
</body>
</html>


End response fields =============

